# Why am I getting an error when migrating? Uninitialized constant AddDates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a new column for a bunch of different items on my site.

```
class AddCreatedatToStreamItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :stream_artworks, :createdat, :date
    add_column :stream_experiments, :createdat, :date
    add_column :stream_photographies, :createdat, :date
    add_column :stream_webs, :createdat, :date
    add_column :stream_socials, :createdat, :date
  end
end
```

Comment: why do you need `:createdat`? Every table already has a column `created_at`.

Comment: Good question. I only need it so I can add projects that are a couple of years old, and sort them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance the filename of the migration is "123123_add_dates.rb" instead of "123123_add_createdat_to_stream_items.rb" (where '123123' is a string of digits, not necessarily '123123')?

The classname of the migration and the filename need to match in the CamelCase => camel_case way.

Comment: This ended up being my folly, a simple filename issue.